# Make my custom list Class return 'list' as type

Tags: python, arrays, list, metaclass

I am writing a custom class which extends the default python lists by adding some new functions such as shuffling , adding, multiplying etc.
The code goes something like this:

```py
class xlist(list):
    def __init__(self, original_list: list):
        self._olist = original_list

    def sumall(self) -> int:
        sum = 0
        for e in self._olist:
            sum += e
        return sum
...
```

But while doing some calculations I needed to get the type of a instance of a `xlist`. I want to do something like this :

```py
>>> from xlist import xlist
>>> x = xlist([1, 2, 3])
>>> type(x)
```

When I do this I get `<class 'xlist.xlist'>` , but I want it to return `list`.

> I am little confused about Metaclasses which seems to be able to solve the problem.

**Any Help?**

Comment: If you want `type(x)` to return `list`, `x` has to be a *direct* instance of `list`, not a subclass of `list`. This has nothing to do with metaclasses; it's simple inheritance.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem; *why* do you want `type` to return `list` instead of `xlist`? You might want `instanceof(x, list)` instead (which will return `True`, because `x` is (indirectly) an instance of `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you expect `type(x)` to return `list` if you're really creating an `xlist`? Your `xlist` inherits from `list`, so every `xlist` object **is** an instance of a `list` since it inherits from it all of its behaviour (and extends by adding some new functionality).

Note that:

```
x = xlist([1, 2, 3])
isinstance(x, list)
```

returns `True`. You might also want to have a look at [Difference between `type()` and `isinstance()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways for Python to check the class of an object - one is calling `type` and the other is checking the `__class__` slot. 
Most times both return the samething, but one can modify the class (for example, by customizing attribute access on the metaclass) so that `__class__` will "lie" and Python code using `myobject.__class__` will get the "false" information.

However, underneath, the "true" `__class__` slot in the `type` object will always hold a reference to the real type - and this can't be falsified. Any C extension, and maybe even a few Python extensions, and the return to `type(myobject)` itself will see the real class.

Changing the contents of this slot actually *changes* the class of your instance. It is feasible from pure Python with a simple `=` attribution - but there are guards in place on this assignment to ensure it is only done across types that have a compatible memory layout. Forcing it to change to an incompatible type (Via an extension, or ctypes) will get your Python runtime to segfault.

All that said, there is no reason to lie about your class to users of your class -they should be able to "see" that the object the are holding is a `xlist` and not a `list`, and that `xlist`s are also `list` objects, due to inheritance. Falsifying this information would be a rather bad practice. On the other hand, there are  few calls, in Python stdlib itself, that require the underlying object to really be a `list` and won't accept subtypes (notoriously Python´s `json.dumps` serialization). That  call has a native code path and won't be fooled by customizing access to `__class__`. However, the same call also has a Python only codepath that is triggered by setting some of the optional arguments (for example, by passing ident=4 on the call). If that is you are trying to achieve (fool some code that requires an strict list)  you have to heck that, and if it is Python code, it is doable. In the specific case of `json.dump`, you'd be better monkeypatching the encoder to use a less strict check than to falsify your object  - because I think the code there uses  `type` for the checing.

So, with all of the above said, the "metaclass trick" to Falsify the return of `.__class__` can be as simple as:

```py
class xlist(list, metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, original_list: list):
        self._olist = original_list
    def sumall(self) -> int:
        sum = 0
        for e in self._olist:
            sum += e
        return sum
    @property
    def __class__(self):
         return list
```

Comment: That was nice explaining. Though with `isinstance()` I was able to complete the functions, still your explanation will be helpful for future.